# What is the use of particular WSO2 Product

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 Products. To Secure a REST web service using OAuth2, There are different combinations used of WSO2 products. I need to know what is the Exactly role and need of Identity Server, When we required WSO-ESB, when we required Data Services Server and when we need Application Server.

Answer (score 0):

**WSO2-IS** You can use this as the IDP for all your applications. WSO2 Identity Server is the central backbone that connects and manages multiple identities across applications, APIs, the cloud, mobile, and Internet of Things devices, regardless of the standards on which they are based.

**WSO2-ESB** ESB is an architecture. It is a set of rules and principles for integrating various applications (mostly heterogeneous systems) together over a bus to achieve a purpose. WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus is a lightweight, high performance, and comprehensive ESB. It effectively addresses integration standards and supports all integration patterns, enabling interoperability among various heterogeneous systems and business applications.

**WSO2-DSS** Behind most application silos are heterogeneous data stores. Most businesses require secure and managed data access across these federated data stores, data service transactions, data transformation and validation. An organization's data exposed as a service, decoupled from the infrastructure where it is stored, is called data services in service oriented architecture (SOA).

You can refer to WSO2 docs for more information regarding each product

- http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/
- http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/
- http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/

Comment: Hi Thusitha, Thanks for difference between above said....Actually i have seen two examples to Secure a web Service... In One Example They have used only WSO2-IS with Consumer app and in Second Example they have used WSO2-IS & WSO2-ESB both. Then i confused to differ them